# Windows App Certification Kit - GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I'd seen a lot conern about the Windows App Certification Kit especially in NGenTest while looking around for a solution..
Shortening the package name didn't work for me and I have not yet submitted any apps in the Marketplace. I am not using any 3rd party libraries other than "Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows 8" But here's my test result in Performance_Test__trace_Launch_1192012_101737.txt.

If you look at the NGemTest, there's something wrong with GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker and I couldn't find any solutions for it. Have you guys encountered this before? What do you think was the problem?

```
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]overridepath - %localappdata%\Microsoft\AppCertKitPerfConfig
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]disablexperf - false
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]xperfpath - ..\Windows Performance Toolkit\xperf.exe
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]xperfflags - Base+FILE_IO+FILE_IO_INIT+CSWITCH+MEMORY
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]xperfuserflags - Microsoft-Windows-Immersive-Shell+Win32HeapRanges
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]xperfminbuffers - 10
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]xperftimeoutmsec - 300000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]systemcfgtimeoutmsec - 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]runngen - true
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]launchtesttimemsec - 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]suspendtesttimemsec - 15000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]launchwarningsec - 3
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]launchfailsec - 5
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]maxcpuusagepercent - 50
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]maxlaunchfileiomb - 50
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]maxsuspendfileiomb - 20
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]maxprivatepagesmb - 25
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[Configuration:LoadSettings]suspendfailsec - 2
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::GetConfig]Override path = C:\Users\Jayson\AppData\Local\Microsoft\AppCertKitPerfConfig\Microsoft.Windows.SoftwareLogo.Performance.dll.config
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: xperfpath
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: disablexperf
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: xperfflags
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: xperfuserflags
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: xperfminbuffers
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: xperftimeoutmsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: systemcfgtimeoutmsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: runNgen
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: launchtesttimemsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: suspendtesttimemsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: launchwarningsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: launchfailsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: maxcpuusagepercent
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: maxlaunchfileioMB
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: maxsuspendfileioMB
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: maxprivatepagesMB
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ConfigFile::ReadStringEntry]Reading entry: suspendfailsec
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Loading Manifest.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Finding the Package node.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Creating namespace and identity node.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Loading applications.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Number of applications: 1.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]New Application.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Loading id.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Id: App.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]EntryPointType: MCA
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Entrypoint value = WACK Genius.exe
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]Creating application node.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[AppXPackage::GetPackageFromManifestFile]node created.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]Retrieving active power scheme.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::GetCurrentPowerScheme]Current Power Scheme Guid : 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]Original power scheme guid: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]Duplicating active power scheme.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]duplicate power scheme guid: 3139fb0e-783f-4f9a-8d99-2a0ff62c8c23
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]Setting duplicate guid: 3139fb0e-783f-4f9a-8d99-2a0ff62c8c23 to active.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -S 3139fb0e-783f-4f9a-8d99-2a0ff62c8c23
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:37 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]setting monitor timeout values.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -monitor-timeout-ac 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -monitor-timeout-dc 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]setting disk timeout values.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -disk-timeout-ac 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -disk-timeout-dc 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]setting standby timeout values.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -standby-timeout-ac 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -standby-timeout-dc 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]setting hibernate timeout values.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -hibernate-timeout-ac 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -X -hibernate-timeout-dc 999
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Setup]Turning off screen saver.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:The app WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8 is not in running state.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]PackageFullName value is : WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]32 Bit Ngen - C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\WACK Genius.exe
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\WACK Genius.exe" /NoDependencies /noroot /version:v4.0.30319 /package:"WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8" /localappdata:"C:\Users\Jayson\AppData\Local\Packages\wsb_e57n2qd78jwy8\AC" /nologo 
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output:
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR:  GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker failed because the worker process died with errorcode -2147221168
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Uninstalling assembly C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\WACK Genius.exe because of an error during compilation: Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04).
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04)
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output end
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR: Failure while compiling: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\WACK Genius.exe
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]32 Bit Ngen - C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.winmd
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.winmd" /NoDependencies /noroot /version:v4.0.30319 /package:"WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8" /localappdata:"C:\Users\Jayson\AppData\Local\Packages\wsb_e57n2qd78jwy8\AC" /nologo 
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output:
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR:  GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker failed because the worker process died with errorcode -2147221168
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Uninstalling assembly C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.winmd because of an error during compilation: Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04).
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04)
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output end
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR: Failure while compiling: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.winmd
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]32 Bit Ngen - C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\MicrosoftAdvertising.winmd
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ngen.exe install "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\MicrosoftAdvertising.winmd" /NoDependencies /noroot /version:v4.0.30319 /package:"WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8" /localappdata:"C:\Users\Jayson\AppData\Local\Packages\wsb_e57n2qd78jwy8\AC" /nologo 
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output:
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR:  GetCorSvcBindToUnregisteredWorker failed because the worker process died with errorcode -2147221168
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Uninstalling assembly C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\MicrosoftAdvertising.winmd because of an error during compilation: Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04).
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Worker exited unexpectedly during startup (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131F04)
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]NGen Command Output end
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]ERROR: Failure while compiling: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\WSB_1.0.0.8_neutral__e57n2qd78jwy8\MicrosoftAdvertising.winmd
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[NGenTest]Error occurred while generating compiling at least one assembly.
Invoking method [Cleanup]
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[Performance::Cleanup]Restoring system power configuration.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Cleanup]Setting original guid: 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e to active.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -S 381b4222-f694-41f0-9685-ff5bb260df2e
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Cleanup]Deleting duplicate guid.
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::Run]Starting Run of: powercfg with arguments -DELETE 3139fb0e-783f-4f9a-8d99-2a0ff62c8c23
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Waiting for exit with timeout of 10000
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[ProcessAction::WaitForExit]Exitcode: 0
program Information: 0 : 11/9/2012 10:17:38 AM INFO:[SystemConfigure::Cleanup]Reseting screen saver.
```

I am using:

- Windows 8 Enterprise Evaluation
- Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows 8

Answer (score 0):

The error code returned from the NGen worker process indicates "Could not read key from registry", though it isn't clear what registry key it was attempting to read when it failed. I'd suggest you to use Process Monitor (procmon.exe, which can be installed from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to record all registry accesses from the NGen worker process (mscorsvw.exe process), to see which one of them failed. Once this is found out, we should be able to figure out how to resolve it.

I'd love to hear from you and know what Process Monitor reveals.